# Where can I find a simple JavaScript based HTML syntax highlighter?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting

Where can I find a simple JavaScript based HTML syntax highlighter?
Simpler is better, and I don't need any line numbers or tricks, just added colors.

If it is the same colors as dreamweaver, even better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some :

- [SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/)
- [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/media/soft/highlight/test.html)
- [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) (As suggested by Joel)
- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) (Ok this one is more fancy, but i already used it and it work well)

Answer (score 5):

There's also google's prettify.js, which is the syntax highligher used on this site:

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: Nice one and simple, i will try to remember it. Last one that impressed me (but it isn't in javascript) is the kasyntaxy@appspot.com bot in Google Wave as it pretty much work in real time, as-you-type.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [prism.js](http://prismjs.com/). I have used many of them and this is by far the simplest one according to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org) a nice one is [dojox.highlight](http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dojox_Highlight_HTML) extension.

Demo page is [here](http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dojox_Highlight_HTML).